# using an ifdef conditional to set a Make flag

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a simple gnu makefile:

```
ifdef $(DEBUGGING)
  CFLAGS = -g -O0 -Wall
else
  CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall
endif

test:
    @echo DEBUGGING is $(DEBUGGING)
    @echo $(CFLAGS)
```

When I invoke it like this, I see that DEBUGGING is set to true, but `ifdef $DEBUGGING` appears to be false:

```
$ DEBUGGING=true make test
DEBUGGING is true
-O3 -Wall
```

I would expect that CFLAGS would be set to "-g -O0 -Wall".  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the *NAME* of the variable in the `ifdef`:

```
ifdef DEBUGGING
```

The value given to `ifdef` is expanded first, and the result is considered a variable name.